# ¿Error al declarar una variable como un Objeto de una clase?

Tags: java

Si tengo tres objetos de la clase Botella:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Instanciar botellas:
    tequila = new Botella("Tequila","Avion",37,750,50,false,4);
    vodka = new Botella("Vodka" ,"Stoli", 40, 750, 40,false ,5);
    whisky = new Botella("Whisky" ,"Four Roses" , 43, 750, 40, true ,3);
```

}

```js
public class Botella {
 
 private String tipo;
 private String marca;
 private int grados;
 private int capacidad;
 private int mlservir;
 private boolean hielo;
 private int precio;
 
}
```

Y luego pregunto al cliente que quiere tomar y asigno una nueva botella que apuntara a la elegida del cliente (Whisky, tequila o Vodka):

```
// preguntar al cliente:
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Que quieres beber?");
    String pedido = input.nextLine();

// asignar producto elegido a botella objeto:
    Botella producto = new Botella();
    if (pedido == "Whisky") {
        producto = whisky
    }
    else if (pedido == "Vodka") {
        producto = vodka
    }
    else if (pedido == "Tequila") {
        producto = tequila
    }
```

**El problema es que con este codigo aunque modifique la propiedad "capacidad" para que sea menor que mlservir, el primer If statement no se recorre nunca:**

```
// Comprobar cantidad y servir copa si es posible:
        if (producto.getCapacidad() < producto.getMlservir()) {
            System.out.println("Lo sentimos, no disponemos de " + pedido + " en estos momentos");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Estoy preparando su " + pedido + "...espere");
            System.out.println("Aqui tiene su " + pedido + ", Disfrute");
        }
```

---

Código completo:

```js
public class Robot {
   
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Instanciar botellas:
  Botella tequila = new Botella("Tequila","Avion",37,750,50,false,4);
  Botella vodka = new Botella("Vodka" ,"Stoli", 40, 750, 40,false ,5);
  Botella whisky = new Botella("Whisky" ,"Four Roses" , 43, 750, 40, true ,3);
  
  // preguntar al cliente:
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Que quieres beber?");
  String pedido = input.nextLine();
  
  // informar del pedido al cliente
   System.out.println("Ha elegido " + pedido);
   System.out.println("...");
   
  // asignar producto elegido a botella objeto:
  Botella producto = new Botella("","",0,0,0,false,0); 
  if (pedido == "Whisky") {
   producto = whisky
  }
  else if (pedido == "Vodka") {
   producto = vodka
  }
  else if (pedido == "Tequila") {
   producto = tequila
  }
  
  // Comprobar cantidad y servir copa si es posible:
   if (producto.getCapacidad() < producto.getMlservir()) {
    System.out.println("Lo sentimos, no disponemos de " + pedido + " en estos momentos");
   }
   else {
    System.out.println("Estoy preparando su " + pedido + "...espere");
    System.out.println("Aqui tiene su " + pedido + ", Disfrute");
   }
  
 }
}
```

```js
public class Botella {
 
 private String tipo;
 private String marca;
 private int grados;
 private int capacidad;
 private int mlservir;
 private boolean hielo;
 private int precio;
 
 // Setters and Getters:
 public String getTipo() {
  return tipo;
 }
 public void setTipo(String tipo) {
  this.tipo = tipo;
 }
 public String getMarca() {
  return marca;
 }
 public void setMarca(String marca) {
  this.marca = marca;
 }
 public int getGrados() {
  return grados;
 }
 public void setGrados(int grados) {
  this.grados = grados;
 }
 public int getCapacidad() {
  return capacidad;
 }
 public void setCapacidad(int capacidad) {
  this.capacidad = capacidad;
 }
 public int getMlservir() {
  return mlservir;
 }
 public void setMlservir(int mlservir) {
  this.mlservir = mlservir;
 }
 public boolean isHielo() {
  return hielo;
 }
 public void setHielo(boolean hielo) {
  this.hielo = hielo;
 }
 public int getPrecio() {
  return precio;
 }
 public void setPrecio(int precio) {
  this.precio = precio;
 }
 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Botella [tipo=" + tipo + ", marca=" + marca + ", grados=" + grados + ", capacidad=" + capacidad
    + ", mlservir=" + mlservir + ", hielo=" + hielo + ", precio=" + precio + "]";
 }
 
 public Botella(String tipo, String marca, int grados, int capacidad, int mlservir, boolean hielo, int precio) {
  super();
  this.tipo = tipo;
  this.marca = marca;
  this.grados = grados;
  this.capacidad = capacidad;
  this.mlservir = mlservir;
  this.hielo = hielo;
  this.precio = precio;
 }
  
 }
```

Comment: Lo único es que, a un `String producto`, le intentarías asignar una instancia de Botella (y eso no va a funcionar así). De ahí en adelante, sólo sería manipular los atributos de la instancia seleccionada y no debería haber problema... salud!

Comment: Como indica @Alfabravo, tu variable producto tendrías que declararla como Botella producto en lugar de String y debería funcionarte.

Comment: @JavierReséndiz Simplemente sustituir "String producto" por "Botella producto"? Me dice que "Botella.capacidad" y "Botella.mlservir" " is not visible"

Comment: Botella producto = new Botella();

Comment: @JavierCake Eso se debe a que son miembros privados. Debes usar los getters y setters para acceder a los valores de dichos miembros.

Comment: @DavElsanto pero si no le añado las propiedades cuando escribo esa línea me da error

Comment: debes usar los getters ejm: producto.getCapacidad()

Comment: @DavElsanto eso está hecho. Pero aun asi me da error :( Voy a actualizar código. EDITO: Ya no me da error si lo lleno con valores vacios ("","",0,0,0,false,0") sin embargo el If statement no se me ejecuta o no lo hace bien

Comment: Cuando lo creas todo a 0, le estás indicando que su cantidad es 0 y su mlservir es 0 con lo cual no te puede entrar al if (producto.getCapacidad() < producto.getMlservir()) porque los 2 son 0. Dependiendo de lo que te pidan no tendrías que hacer esa comparación, sino comparar con los 3 productos que creas al principio para ver si tienes existencias. Además, como te han dicho, esto no está bien producto = whisky, tiene que ser producto.tipo=Whisky.

Answer (score 1):

Revisando tu código elimina la parte de los **static** y en tu método **main** cambia por lo siguiente:

```
//eliminar o comentar
static Botella tequila;
static Botella vodka;
static Botella whisky;

//cambiarlos por lo siguientes dentro del main
Botella tequila = new Botella("Tequila", "Avion", 37, 750, 50, false, 4);
Botella vodka = new Botella("Vodka", "Stoli", 40, 750, 40, false, 5);
Botella whisky = new Botella("Whisky", "Four Roses", 43, 750, 40, true, 3);
```

Creo que por el hecho que los declaras como **static** estos se crean con datos nulos más info de la directiva [**static**](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2015/09/17/la-directiva-static-en-java/).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cambia los simbolos de iguial **==** por la funcion **equals** en tu if:

```
if (pedido.equals("Whisky")) {
    producto = whisky;
} else if (pedido.equals("Vodka")) {
    producto = vodka;
} else if (pedido.equals("Tequila")) {
    producto = tequila;
}
```

Comment: Entiendo, ahora no me da error en ningun lado pero sin embargo el If Statement no me funciona correctamente. (es decir, modifico la propiedad "capacidad" de tequila para que se cumpla el primer If statement, y no lo recorre. Sigue pasando al else.

Comment: Edito: El problema parace ser que la Botella pedido no se asigna a ninguna Botella tequila, vodka o whisky. Después de pasar el primer If Statement del código, he hecho un printout de Pedido, y no ha heredado los parametros de la Botella tequila, cuando lo debería haber hecho. ¿Por qué?

Comment: aumento una corrección

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que, en el If que no te entra, no haces la comparación correcta, sería así:

```
public class Robot {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Instanciar botellas:
    Botella tequila = new Botella("Tequila","Avion",37,750,50,false,4);
    Botella vodka = new Botella("Vodka" ,"Stoli", 40, 750, 40,false ,5);
    Botella whisky = new Botella("Whisky" ,"Four Roses" , 43, 750, 40, true ,3);

    // preguntar al cliente:
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Que quieres beber?");
    String pedido = input.nextLine();

    // informar del pedido al cliente
        System.out.println("Ha elegido " + pedido);
        System.out.println("...");

    // asignar producto elegido a botella objeto:
    Botella producto = new Botella("","",0,0,0,false,0); 
    if (pedido.Equals("Whisky")) {
        producto.setTipo("whisky") //Asignamos el valor a la variable del objeto

        //Ahora comprobamos que hay o no disponible
        if (producto.getCapacidad() < whisky.getMlservir()) { //Comparamos con wisky, no con producto
            System.out.println("Lo sentimos, no disponemos de " + pedido + " en estos momentos");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Estoy preparando su " + pedido + "...espere");
            System.out.println("Aqui tiene su " + pedido + ", Disfrute");
        }
    }
    else if (pedido.Equals("Vodka")) {   //Asignamos el valor a la variable del objeto
        producto.setTipo("vodka")

        //Ahora comprobamos que hay o no disponible
        if (producto.getCapacidad() < vodka.getMlservir()) { //Comparamos con vodka, no con producto
            System.out.println("Lo sentimos, no disponemos de " + pedido + " en estos momentos");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Estoy preparando su " + pedido + "...espere");
            System.out.println("Aqui tiene su " + pedido + ", Disfrute");
        }
    }
    else if (pedido.Equals("Tequila")) { //Asignamos el valor a la variable del objeto
        producto.setTipo("tequila")

        //Ahora comprobamos que hay o no disponible
        if (producto.getCapacidad() < tequila.getMlservir()) { //Comparamos con tequila, no con producto
            System.out.println("Lo sentimos, no disponemos de " + pedido + " en estos momentos");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Estoy preparando su " + pedido + "...espere");
            System.out.println("Aqui tiene su " + pedido + ", Disfrute");
        }
    }

}
}
```

He aprovechado los if donde asignas lo que ha pedido para comprobar si hay o no cantidad suficiente para servir, sino tendrías que hacer otros 3 if ya que hay que comparar con la botella que el cliente haya pedido.

Quedaría mejor si lo metes en un método para no repetir código pero eso te lo dejo a tí.

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: repites mucho codigo y tiene el mismo error del if

Comment: @DavElsanto que he repetido código ya lo he puesto yo, si lees, indico que para no repetir código lo meta en una función.